# Просмотр информации об ошибках в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Запускаю приложение на телефоне. При возникновении ошибок в android monitor не выводится информация о них. Но если делать запуск на эмуляторе, то ошибки выводятся в android monitor. Можно ли как-то увидеть возникшие исключения, если запускать приложение на реальном устройстве?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device

Comment: поногло ,.,.,.,?

Comment: Я сейчас не могу проверить. Вечером попытаюсь. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: К сожалению, это не то, что мне нужно

Answer (score 1):

Используйте try/catch в местах вероятных ошибок. В catch Используйте родителя Exception, получайте текст ошибки и выводите в лог.`try{//ваш код, который мождет содержать ошибки} catch (Exception ex){ Log.d("log_tag",ex.getMessage());}`

Comment: что? не проще ли без этого? в логи все равно будет выхлоп ошибки

Comment: @Flippy НВозможно проще) о это же не значит что не нужно отлавливать ошибки в Try/catch?)

Comment: значит, но если это необходимо (метод/конструктор с `throws` или например если нужно открыть Google Play и отловить в catch случай когда он не установлен